# The page was not displayed because the Request URI is too long

Tags: iis, iis-8, network-share

I try to map a network share to an application in IIS8 but when i try to retrieve a test file i get this error in plain black text:

```
The page was not displayed because the Request URI is too long.
```

The url i test (on the server) is a short simple one:

http://localhost/server/test.jpg

I tested from another computer with IP but got the same error.

This is the information I get from the IIS log

```
2017-09-13 07:56:23 ::1 GET /server/test.jpg - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 414 0 87 0
```

Why does it complain about the request URI? Is this a generic error?

Answer (score 1):

It was a permission problem. The IIS user did not have read-rights to the folder. Changed to use application pool identity instead and now its working.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was using a virtual directory and the double hop issue with authentication where the folder didn't have the credentials tied to it.  Needed to manually set it on the folder.

https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue

Comment: Fix for me was to change virtual directory "Connect As" to Specific user.